# JQuery, JS Confirm form submission not working

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, form-submit

```
    jQuery("form.areyousure").submit(function(e){
    if (!confirm("Are you sure?")){
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    } else {
        jQuery("form.areyousure").submit(this);
    }
});
```

There are a couple forms on this page with class=areyousure.  I just need a simple check.  The confirm dialog pops up, but on "OK", I am redirected to /admin/undefined.  I've tried with and without the 'else', with and without 'this' in the submit(). Also tried:

```
} else {
this.submit();
    }
```

This is wrapped in a jQuery(document).ready(function(){.

Here's the form.  There is a delete and a clear form for each of several items.  So, currently there is only 2 forms on the page, but there could be several X 2.

```
<form method="post" id="landingpagessettings" class="areyousure" >
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="dbid">
<input type="submit"  value="Clear" name="e-button">
<input type="hidden" name="e-action" value="sth" />
</form>
```

Comment: What's written in the `<form>` action attribute? Also, you don't have to call `submit()` within the event handler - just don't invoke `e.preventDefault()` when you indeed want to submit the form.

Comment: Post a sample `<form>` that's not working as you would expect.

Comment: `"I am redirected to /admin/undefined"` - Not by the code posted you aren't.  What is the form action being submitted?  `"There are a couple forms on this page with class=areyousure."` - In that case, I would expect the behavior of that `else` block to be unreliable.  You probably only want to submit one form, not all of them simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
  if (!confirm("Are you sure?"))
    return false;
  else
    return true;
}
```

Also, `action` attibute may be normal (example `/submit`). Check form ID. Script must be after form html code.

Comment: How exactly does it help, and how this is better than plain `return confirm('Are you sure?')`?